# Cannot change file name in laravel request

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I'm sending some data from a form, one field is type file like this(simplified version) that is an avatar image:

```
<form id="userform" method="POST" action="/users/store" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="fields-ctn">
        <input class="field" id="avatar" type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/*">
        <input class="field" id="name" type="text" name="name" >
        <input class="field" id="email" type="text" name="email" >
        <input class="field" id="password" type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

in the related controller I have something like this (simplified version) that checks if there is a file in the request and stores it in a dedicated folder with a unique name, then **(and here is the problem)** it will change the value of the avatar field in the request, so I can store it later in the db with the new unique name

```
// Update User
public function update(Request $request){

    // Upload avatar
    if( $request->hasFile('avatar') ) {

        // Unique file name
        $avatarName = $request['name'].'-'.uniqid().'-avatar.jpg';

        // I save the file in the avatar folder with its new name
        $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
            'avatars', $avatarName, 'public'
        );
        
        $request['avatar'] = $avatarName;
        
    } else {
        $request['avatar'] = config('options.default_avatar');
    }

...

}
```

no matter how much I tried, I cannot change the name in the request, I tried in so many ways

```
$request['avatar'] = $avatarName;
$request->avatar = $avatarName;
$request->merge(['avatar'=>'$avatarName'])
```

if I try debugging

```
dd($request->all())
```

I always obtain this Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile, where the value of avatar doesn't changes

```
array:7 [
  "action" => "update"
  "id" => "50"
  "_token" => "d0WSL69fEVEb71HDnXoirQJ2fsfe9hes3ZmCuyff"
  "name" => "Lauras"
  "password" => "$2y$10$g.4dGPWfEA2LjhZBcXFUiOTqwjM8PCHuooaaHnUWyPFoJFQihlDkC"
  "password_confirmation" => "nt1access"
  "avatar" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#313
    -test: false
    -originalName: "52F.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpWbVial"
    basename: "phpWbVial"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpWbVial"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpWbVial"
    aTime: 2022-07-13 22:08:15
    mTime: 2022-07-13 22:08:15
    cTime: 2022-07-13 22:08:15
    inode: 406627
    size: 200630
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

I can change any value in the request before I update by simply doing

```
$request['field'] = $newFieldName;
```

but I cannot change the avatar field. something really strange is that if I do this

```
$request->avatar = $avatarName;
dd($request->avatar);
```

it will output the $avatarName that I want, but if I do

```
$request->avatar = $avatarName;
dd($request);
```

it will output again this Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile stuffs.

For now the only way to fix this, is to store the entire request in another variable and then manipulate the new variable, before I update the db, in this way

```
$data = $request->all();
```

this is not so bad ok, but I cannot understand why this is happening, is like everytime I call $request it will reset only the avatar field to the original value.

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging and I think I found out the issue.

[In Symfony's `Request` class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#method___construct), there's a property `$request` which is where `$_POST` is stored, and a property `$files` which is where `$_FILES` is stored.

[Laravel's `Request` class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L420) extends [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/ArrayAccess), and its `OffsetSet` method [looks like this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L730):

```php
public function offsetSet($offset, $value): void 
{ 
    $this->getInputSource()->set($offset, $value); 
}
```

And the `getInputSource` method [looks like this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L420):

```php
protected function getInputSource()
{
    if ($this->isJson()) {
        return $this->json();
    }

    return in_array($this->getRealMethod(), ['GET', 'HEAD']) ? $this->query : $this->request;
}
```

In your case, your request isn't JSON, and it's not using the `GET` or `HEAD` methods, so the input source you're modifying is `$this->request`.

This means that when you set `$request['field'] = $newFieldName;` you're setting `$this->request['field']` to `$newFieldName` as you expect.

It also means that when you set `$request['avatarName'] = $avatarName;`, you're also setting `$this->request['avatarName']` to `$avatarName` as you expect.

So what's the problem?

When you convert a Laravel `Request` object to an array, it uses the [`toArray()` method on that class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L691):

```php
public function toArray(): array
{
    return $this->all();
}
```

And in the `all()` method (inherited from `InteractsWithInput`) [we find the issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L256):

```php
public function all($keys = null)
{
    $input = array_replace_recursive($this->input(), $this->allFiles());
    ...
```

[`$this->input()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Concerns/InteractsWithInput.php#L280) is getting values from the result of `getInputSource()`, which is to say Symfony's `$request` property containing the values of `$_POST`, and overwriting it with the values from `$this->allFiles()`, which is getting values from `$files`, which contains the values of `$_FILES`.

---

### So what does this all mean?

Long story short, this is a weird quirk of Laravel's implementation of `ArrayAccess` on the `Request` class. When you read/write to a `Request` object with array notation, you're really just reading/writing the variables which were `$_POST`ed (or the JSON-encoded body or `$_GET` variables if your request was json-encoded or a `GET`/`HEAD` request).

If you want to continue down this path, you'll need to modify your `$request->files` property. It's a Symfony [`FileBag`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/FileBag.php), which you can change with the `set()` method:

```php
$request->files->set('avatarName', /*Your modified UploadedFile object*/);
```

Comment: Your explanation is clear but the solution with set() doesn't works I tried                 `$request->files->set('avatar', ['something']);` and then  `dd($request);` here I can see the filebag changed but again if I do `dd($request->all())`; it will show me the original file object

Comment: Hmm, might have got something wrong there. I'll have to have a look tomorrow.

Comment: I just didn't found an answer for this, but i think something's related with [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/delete-parameters-from-request?page=1&replyId=367037). anyway it was a good dive